# How to remove everything from a substring on in Rust

Tags: rust

I need to remove all words on one side of a word in a string. I did try `str::strip_suffix`, but it didn't do anything.

Here's an example of what I need:

```
"Hello world, this is a sentence."
```

(Remove all words from the word "this" and beyond)

```
"Hello world, "
```

Comment: [`strip_suffix` does work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f4dcf9c0440b3ff904e5ae7adc06dd8c). Maybe you should post your code and ask why it doesn't in your case?

Comment: `strip_suffix` does not *modify* the string, it *returns* a modified string. But hard to say if that's your problem, without seeing your code.

Answer (score 3):

Without using `String` methods, you can also slice on the index returned by [`find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.find):

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = "Hello world, this is a sentence.";
    let b = &a[0..a.find("this").unwrap_or(a.len())];
    
    println!("{b}");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut msg = "Hello world, this is a sentence.";
    if let Some((m, _)) = msg.split_once("this") {
        msg = m;
    }
    println!("{msg:?}");    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`String::replace_range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.replace_range).

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("Hello world, this is a sentence.");
    let offset = s.find("this").unwrap_or(s.len());
    
    s.replace_range(offset.., "");
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Comment: Alternative: `s.truncate(offset)`.